# Mixing tpl and items in Sencha Touch 2

Tags: sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I have a list detail view which works fine - it has a tpl and no items. I would like to add other components so I added an items array but now the tpl no longer shows. I have tried keeping the tpl in the main config and also adding it as a component to no avail (how does the data know where the appropriate tpl is located btw?) - I guess ideally I would like to be able to inject my list data anywhere on the page - i..e above and below and in between items. How is this done?

```
Ext.define("App.view.ListDetail", {
    extend: "Ext.Container",
    record: undefined,
    config: {
        layout: 'vbox',
        style: "padding: 5px;",
        scrollable: true,
        //  tpl: ["<div>", "name<br />verified star<br />avatar pic", "</div>"].join(""), // this works fine if I have no items array


        //adding this causes above tpl to no longer render
        items: [
        {
            xtype: 'component',
            tpl: ["<div>", "name<br />verified star<br />avatar pic", "</div>"].join(""),  //this does nothing
        },
        {
            xtype: 'panel',
            //more stuff here

        },
        ] 
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately you cannot mix `tpl` and `items` configurations together, as they both update the html of the component.

To achieve what you want, you will need to add another item into the `items` configuration, ensuring you position it where you want it, and then add your custom `tpl` config into that item.

Also, I'm sure you are aware, but you need to use the `data` configuration alongside `tpl`, or it will not show anything.

```
Ext.define("App.view.ListDetail", {
    extend: "Ext.Container",
    record: undefined,
    config: {
        layout: 'vbox',
        style: "padding: 5px;",
        scrollable: true,

        //adding this causes above tpl to no longer render
        items: [
            {
                xtype: 'component',
                tpl: ["<div>", "name<br />verified star<br />avatar pic", "</div>"].join("")  //this does nothing
            },
            {
                xtype: 'panel'
                //more stuff here

            },
            {
                tpl: ["<div>", "name<br />verified star<br />avatar pic", "</div>"].join("") // this works fine if I have no items array
            }
        ]
    }
});
```